Poetry Cannot install bitsandbytes 0.43.1 in python 3.11
When I try poetry adding bitsandbytes, i get:
  - Installing bitsandbytes (0.43.1): Failed

  RuntimeError

  Unable to find installation candidates for bitsandbytes (0.43.1)

  at ~/Library/Application Support/pypoetry/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/poetry/installation/chooser.py:74 in choose_for
       70│
       71│             links.append(link)
       72│
       73│         if not links:
    →  74│             raise RuntimeError(f"Unable to find installation candidates for {package}")
       75│
       76│         # Get the best link
       77│         chosen = max(links, key=lambda link: self._sort_key(package, link))
       78│

Cannot install bitsandbytes.

I am not sure how to get around this when installing this package using bitsandbytes. I tried accessing the poetry shell then doing:
pip install bitsandbytes

which picks up version 0.42.01, but it does not seem to find 0.43.1 while poetry add picks up this version which is what I need.
